# Upsert data from csv into MongoDb

Tags: python, json, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

**I have been able to insert data from a csv into a MongoDB by using using PyMongo in the below code.**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import time
import json

client = MongoClient()
db = client.MainDB
col = db.Test


def csv_to_json(filename, header=0):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False, sep='|', low_memory=True)
    return json.loads(data.to_dict(orient='records'))

try: 
    col.insert_many(csv_to_json('main.csv'))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Now, I will have to be updating this collection daily with the same csv but with different values for certain fields.
This is what i came up with and it didnt work.
How do i go about this, please.**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import json
import time


starttime = time.time()
client = MongoClient()
db = client.MainDB
col = db.Test


def csv_to_json(filename, header=0):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=header, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False, sep='|', low_memory=True)
    return data.to_dict(orient='dict')

try:
    col.update({}, csv_to_json('main.csv'),upsert=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: What about using the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) tool? Should be much more efficient.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheir Can I use mongoimport tool in a python script?

Comment: I would assume you can call an arbitrary executable in Python: https://www.newbedev.com/python/howto/6-ways-to-call-external-command-in-python/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `db.collect.bulk_write()` in conjugation with `update_many()` (if you want to perform multiple actions, otherwise `update_many()` alone would do) to update the values.

[Here's](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write) an example as to how you can use `bulk_write`.

For `update_many()`, you could have something like this:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:1001/")
db = client["mydatabase"]
collect = mydb["customers"]

my_query = { "address": { "$regex": "ABC[0-9]" } }
new_values = { "$set": { "name": "DEF" } }

x = collect.update_many(myquery, newvalues)
```

The documentation for it can be found [here](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/operations.html#pymongo.operations.UpdateMany).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I made this update:

col.update_many({}, csv_to_json('main.csv'), upsert=True)


And i had this error:
'update' command document too large

My csv is about 100MB